# React filters products in a one go

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I just came from the interview, I have implemented multiple filter feature in my assignment.

assignment is live here: https://tooth-store.netlify.app/

here is my code where I am filtering with according to the value of filters state.

```js
  const filterData = () => {
    let data = [...products];

    if (byCategory !== 'all') {
      data = data.filter((item) => {
        return item.category.toLowerCase() === byCategory.toLowerCase();
      });
    }

    if (byRating !== 'all') {
      data = data.filter((item) => Math.floor(item.rating.rate) == byRating);
    }

    if (bySearch != '') {
      data = data.filter((item) =>
        item.title.toLowerCase().includes(bySearch.toLowerCase())
      );
    }

    return data;
  };
```

Interviewer told me if we will be having a lot of products then going with this approach is not a good idea, so we have to filter at a one go not for all single value of filters.

example: category filter is applied earlier, and now we are changing the rating then it will again filters the category first. so filter it in a one go.

**Can anyone explain me in a detail how I have to deal with this, I got blank at that time, but now i am guessing i simply have to check for all filters values with && operator in a single filter**

Is there is any other best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a common function, where you can check the category against data, here I give you an example in the below code, I make a common function where I get a two param, one is `item` this is list of items and the second is `category` user which category against wants  data, In the function, I define the some categories array, you can store the categories dynamically in the state and then check if category exists in the categories array, If exists then you can filter the data against the categories list and If you want to see the full example [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sanne-gobozc?file=/src/App.js:0-1912).

```
const func = (item, category) => {
  let newArr = [];
  if (category !== "all") {
    const categories = ["electronics", "men's clothing", "jewelery"];
    const ratings = [1.9, 2.5, 6.7];
    if (categories.includes(category)) {
      newArr = item.category.toLowerCase() === category.toLowerCase();
    } else if (ratings.includes(category)) {
      newArr = Math.floor(item.rating.rate) === category;
    } else {
      newArr = item.title.toLowerCase().includes(category.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
  return newArr;
};

const filterData = () => {
  let data = [...products];
  data = data.filter((item) => {
    return func(item, byCategory);
  });
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method where your filter option will run for only one type at a time just you have to pass a parameter like this

```
const filterData = (type) => {
let data = [...products];

if (byCategory !== 'all' && type == 'cat') { // call this filterData('cat') 
  data = data.filter((item) => {
    return item.category.toLowerCase() === byCategory.toLowerCase();
  });
}

if (byRating !== 'all'&& type == 'rate') { // call this filterData('rate') 
  data = data.filter((item) => Math.floor(item.rating.rate) == byRating);
}

if (bySearch != ''&& type == 'search') { // call function by filterData('search')
  data = data.filter((item) =>
    item.title.toLowerCase().includes(bySearch.toLowerCase())
  );
}

return data;
};
```